# How to link php/html pages to each other in an online web server? Plus issues with mysqli

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a simple web page for my bio where anyone who wants to view my bio signs up and then signs in with a username and password in the front page (yes, this is dumb but it's only for a simple project and I don't intend for this to be anything but that). The problem is that when I upload those HTML and PHP files to an online server, the pages do not work or register a login even though it should work.

I have 8 files total that handle the login system and main page. 
The first file is the header file which contains the HTML code for the home page and a few lines of PHP code which deal with the session_start login and an if-else statement that presides over maintaining the user in a logged-in session. It is extremely messy and my HTML coding is horrible so there are a lot of redundant lines of code for buttons and lists I'm not using but plan to use once I figure everything else.

The second file is index.php. This file contains two PHP lines of code at the beginning and end which require the "header.php" and the "footer.php". In between is code which basically gives the user a message whether they're logged in or logged out.

The third file is the footer.php. This is exactly what it is, a simple footer file with ending footer and HTML tags, nothing more.

The fourth file is signup.php. Again, just like index.php, it contains lines of code "require = 'header.php'" and "require = 'footer.php'" at the beginning and end. In between is code with a bunch of if-elseif-else that handles whether a user inputted characters into the field and the errors that result when something goes wrong.

The last four files are files that go in an "unseen" folder in the root and handle the background tasks.

The fifth file is 'loginunseen.php'. This file deals with the login stuff.

The sixth file is 'signupunseen.php'. This file deals with the sign up stuff and checks if there are duplicates in the database.

The seventh file is 'logoutunseen.php'. This is a small file which "logs out" the user from a session through a few of session_x(); statements.

The eighth file is 'databasehandlerunseen.php'. This file performs the login into the main SQL database which stores the user's information. When I'm using locally, I change the username, password, and database for use on my local server but when I upload it to the online server that has a different password, username, and database that I use, I make sure to change the variables.

And finally, in MySQL, there's a database that I'm using with a table called "users" with entries "idUsers int(11) PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL", "usernameUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL", "emailUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL", "passwordUsers LONGTEXT NOT NULL"

Im using a CSS file to style the website but that's not important.

****************header.php***************

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Read about me!</title>
    <link href="sitelook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>

        <div class="row">


            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo1.png">
            </div>


            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href=""> Sign in </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> About </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> FAQ  </a></li>
                <li><a href=""> Log Out </a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>


        <div class ="header-login">
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
                echo '<form action="unseen/logoutunseen.php" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
            </form>';
            } else {
                echo '<form action="unseen/loginunseen.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="username">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
                </form>';
            }
            ?>
            <a href="signup.php" class="header-signup">Sign up</a>
        </div>


        <div class="hero">
            <h1>Want to read my bio? Login!</h1>
            <div class="button">
                <a href="" class="btn btn-one"> Log in</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </nav>
</header>
```

****************index.php*****************

```
    <?php
    require "header.php";
    ?>

        <main>
            <div class="wrapper-main">
                <section class="section-default">
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
                        echo '<p class="login-status">Logged in!</p>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<p class="logout-status">Logged out!</p>';
                    }
                    ?>

                </section>
            </div>
        </main>

    <?php
    require "footer.php";
    ?>
```

****************signup.php*****************

```
?php
require "header.php";
?>
//in form class, check unseen/signup.php
    <main>
        <div class="wrapper-main">
            <section class="section-default">
                <h1>Sign up to read my bio!</h1>
                <?php
                    if (isset($_GET['error'])){
                        if($_GET['error'] == "emptyfields"){
                            echo '<p class="signuperror">Fill in the fields</p>';
                        } elseif ($_GET['error'] == "invaliduidmail"){
                            echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username and email</p>';
                        } elseif ($_GET['error'] == "invaliduid"){
                            echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username</p>';
                        } elseif ($_GET['error'] == "invalidmail"){
                            echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid email</p>';
                        } elseif ($_GET['error'] == "usertaken"){
                            echo '<p class="signuperror">Username taken</p>';
                        }
                    } elseif ($_GET['success'] == "signup"){ //success=signup
                        echo '<p class="signupsuccess">You are signed!</p>';
                    }
                ?>
                <form class="form-signup" action="unseen/signupunseen.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="username">
                    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="email">
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="password">
                    <button type="submit" name="signup-submit">Signup</button>

                </form>

            </section>
        </div>
    </main>

<?php
require "footer.php";
?>
```

***************footer.php***************

```
<footer>

</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

*****************loginunseen.php***************

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) { //in require 'databasehandlerunseen.php check if path file is correct
    require 'unseen/databasehandlerunseen.php';

    $mailuserid = $_POST['mailuid'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($mailuserid) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    } else { //checks if the user's password inputted is correct or in the database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernameUsers=? or emailUsers=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuserid, $mailuserid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $passCheck = password_verify($password, $row['passwordUsers']);
                if ($passCheck == FALSE){
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
                    exit();
                } elseif ($passCheck == TRUE){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['userUserID'] = $row['usernameUsers'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=successpass");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpassword");
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
                exit();

            }
        }
    }
}
    else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

***********signupunseen.php****************

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {
    require 'unseen/databasehandlerunseen.php';
    //now to fetch information from form. Use 'uid', 'mail', 'pwd' from signup.php
    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $email = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];


    //error handlers to check if user inputted correct info
    //check if fields are empty
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=" . $username . "&email=" . $email);
        exit();
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid");
        exit();
    } //checks for invalid email
    elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();

    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    } // This else statement checks if user signs in with a username already taken
    else {
        // MySQL query statement, make sure entries are correct
        // Must use prepared statements for extra layer of security
        $sql = "SELECT usernameUsers FROM users WHERE usernameUsers=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=" . $email);
                exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (usernameUsers,emailUsers, passwordUsers) VALUES(?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                } else { // creating hash of passwords inputted for security. PASSWORD_DEFAULT IS SECURE AND UPDATED
                    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $password);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?success=signup");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();

}
```

************logoutunseen.php*************

```
<?php
//logs you out
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../index.php");
?>
```

**********databasehandlers.php*****************

```
<?php

//these variables need to be changed before uploaded to online server
$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
//dBName is name of the database in mysql. If using locally, it's loginsys. Online database, it's bremy_project
$dBName = "NAME OF DATABASE HERE";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

I expect to be able to view the other PHP pages but I'm always stuck on the main page. When I use these files on the online server, nothing goes through and no username, password or email entry is saved in the database even though it should be going through. The only thing I can think of is that there are incorrect file paths in the code.

Comment: There's a lot going on here... please narrow this down to a single specific problem.  Start by ensuring PHP is running with a simple `phpinfo()`.  Check your error logs as well.

Comment: Okay, for starters, when I try to sign up or login, nothing happens. I'm not really getting an error code, all that happens when I try to sign up or input a username and password is a refresh of the page with nothing happening. The username and password are recognized by the browser as going in (since it gives me a message saying "Do you want to save this password for blah") but when I check the database and the table, it's empty. Now, I do have a ton of useless buttons that I haven't established in the code but the username, password and login buttons should be defined and working but don't.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to debug your php code by enabling PHP ERROR REPORTING.
The quickest way to display all php errors and warnings is to add these lines to your PHP code files:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

after adding these lines to your php files, you will see some error and know why you're always stuck on the main page

Comment: Alright, so I went through each file with those lines you recommended and I got one error. For signup.php, I got a notice saying "Undefined index: success in .... on line 22.

Comment: You should use to check to know array key is set or not using isset() function.